# My toggle-input in React is giving false accessibility

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, accessibility

I have accessibility problem with a toggle input that I am checking with VoiceOver on mac. The issue is that when I press the toggle input to off - VoiceOver says on - and vice versa. How to I make it correct i.e VoiceOver says off when it is in fact ticked off? This is how the code looks now, all labels are correct to each toggle input,it is only the VoiceOver that is giving incorrect information on whether it's on or off.

**Toggle.tsx**

```
<div className={`flex items-center justify-between py-4 ${className}`}>
      <div id={labelId}>{label}</div>
      <label htmlFor={id} className="inline-flex cursor-pointer items-center">
        <span className="relative">
          <input
            id={id}
            aria-labelledby={labelId}
            type="checkbox"
            className="peer absolute opacity-0"
            value={toggledOn ? 1 : 0}
            onChange={onToggle}
          />
          <span
            className={`block h-6 w-10 rounded-full shadow-inner ${
              toggledOn ? 'bg-bui-color-green' : 'bg-bui-color-gray'
            } peer-focus-outline`}
          />
          <span
            className={`focus-within:shadow-outline absolute inset-y-0 left-0 mt-[0.125rem] ml-[0.125rem] block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-bui-color-white shadow transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out ${
              toggledOn ? 'ml-[-0.125rem] translate-x-full transform' : ''
            }`}
          />
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
```

Used in **Settings.tsx**

```
{loading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          data?.user?.savedSearches?.map((it: any) => (
            <Toggle
              id={it.searchId}
              className={toggleClassNames}
              key={it.searchId}
              label={it?.title}
              toggledOn={savedSearchesValues[it.searchId as keyof typeof savedSearchesValues]}
              onToggle={() => {
                handleSearchToggleChange(
                  it.searchId,
                  !savedSearchesValues[it.searchId as keyof typeof savedSearchesValues],
                  it.emailFrequency,
                );
              }}
            />
          ))
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly using the [checkbox input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox). If you adhere to the standards, it will work fine.

A checkbox needs to expose its state via the `checked` attribute. Also the [ARIA standard](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#checkbox) would expect the state to be exposed via `aria-checked`.

You can also checkout the [Switch pattern on the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/switch/switch.html), which uses a button instead, and also changes the label On/Off. It also uses `aria-checked` to expose the state.

[image: A Switch with label Notifications, the toggle is switched to the right and green, saying On]

---

You are trying to change the label of the checkbox based on some internal react state. Dynamically changing labels and roles seems to not be supported reliably in different assistive technology in general.

In your case though, it might have to do with the screen reader deciding based on the actual `checked` state whether to re-read the label. I’m not sure anymore how it works for this managed component, but might `checked` get changed before the label changes?

**The labels have code smell**

The code uses three different approaches to provide an accessible name for the checkbox. Currently all three techniques, `aria-labelledby`, `for` and a wrapping `<label>` are used.

It’s really difficult to figure out which technique will take precedence, and it might depend very much on the used browser and assistive technology if this works.

Checking in Firefox, the `aria-label` takes precedence, so On/Off is not exposed at all.